# как узнать расширение файла при его скачивании?

Tags: python

Загружаю файл с сайта через библиотеки `requests`. При скачивании получаю base64.Как узнать расширение загружаемого файла?

Comment: Для начала нужно определиться с тем, что такое "тип". Что это?

Comment: *расширение файла

Comment: Придётся использовать [python-magic](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic) или [puremagic](https://github.com/cdgriffith/puremagic).

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev как их установить?

Comment: Как и любую другую библиотеку. По ссылкам описан процесс.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev всё установлено, как использовать magic для этой задачи?

Answer (score 2):

После долгих поисков нашёл рабочий вариант:

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import magic
import mimetypes
import urllib.request

data = requests.get("http://bgpics.ru/pictures/1366x768/5834-nyu-york-bruklinskiy-most-fotooboi-1366x768.jpg", headers={'User-Agent': str(UserAgent().random)}).content
mime_type = magic.from_buffer(data, mime=True)
file_ext = mimetypes.guess_extension(mime_type)
```

Если кто-то знает более оптимальный вариант, пожалуйста дополните мой ответ.

Comment: После долгих? Вам же сразу написали, что вы получаете бинарные данные, а не base64, поэтому надо просто убрать строку с декодированием.